# Is it possible to identify the image from which a docker container was built?

Tags: image, docker, networking, containers

The context to my question is as follows:
I have a few docker images that I have built, and from those, I have got a few containers running, on various networks.

When I use `docker inspect network <network_name>`, it returns json data, containing a "Containers" structure.
When I used `docker run ...` to create the containers, I forgot to use the --name option, so the container ID is just a long random string. As such, I can't work out what that container is.

Given this context, is it possible to identify the image from which a docker container was built?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `docker inspect` , but do it on the container and not on the network:

`docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Image}}' $INSTANCE_ID`

where $INSTANCE_ID is the container ID